# Realm Flexible Sync Subscription to objects with links

Tags: kotlin, realm

Let's say I have a BookCollection RealmObject with a linking property 'books' that is a RealmList, where Book is another RealmObject. As a user, I want to subscribe to multiple BookCollections with access to all the Books as well. Using Flexible Sync, I can just create subscriptions to the BookCollections directly (via an id field or something). However, this itself does not give me access to the RealmList 'books' property, because Realm would give me an error saying that the linking property can't be found. I also can't define a Flexible Sync subscription to all Book's belonging to subscribed BookCollection's, since Flexible Sync doesn't allow queries on links. The Book object can't be an EmbeddedRealmObject, either, since it might be shared between multiple BookCollection's.

What's the best way to get around this? Thanks.

Comment: Describing the issue doesn't really provide enough information to answer your coding specific question - the question needs to include the code you've attempted. Including your Realm models also helps us understand the structure of your objects and their relationship. A linkingObject is an *inverse* relationship, not a forward relationship and it's not clear how that applies in your question. Can you clarify what's being asked, include your Realm models and the code you've attempted? Then we can take a look.

Comment: The question isn't that deep. If an object I'm subscribed to has a relationship to another object(BookCollection contains one or more Book's), how do I ensure that the other object in the relationship is also subscribed to, to prevent a scenario where I access a subscribed BookCollection, but get a Realm error when I try to access one or more of its Book's, which aren't subscribed to?

Comment: Generally speaking, all object models to be accessed will need to be included in the Flex sync setup.